# Using Enums that are in an external dll

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, enums

I have a project I am working that will involve creating one DLL that will be used across multiple other sites. Inside this DLL we need to reference about 10 Enums. The values of these Enums however will be different for each site the DLL is used on. For example:

MyBase.dll may have a class MyClass with an attribute of type MyEnum.

MyBase.dll is then referenced in MySite. MyStie will also reference MyEnums.dll which will contain the values for the MyEnum type.

Is there any way to accomplish this? While building MyBase.dll, I know what enums will exist in side of MyEnums.dll. The problem is I cannot build MyBase.dll without specifically referenceing the MyEnums.dll, which is not created until the MyBase.dll is used in a specific project.

I hope that makes sense and hope I can find an answer here.

Thanks.

Edit:

Thanks for all the comments. It will take a few reads to completely understand, but let me try to give a better example of what I am looking at here.

Lets say the following code is in my DLL that will be put into various projects. Status is an enum.

```
public Class MyClass
{
    private Status _currentStatus;

    public Status CurrentStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentStatus;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(Status newStatus)
    {
        _currentStatus = newStatus;
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is the define the possible values for Status in the individual projects. So in this DLL, I will never reference what values might be in the Status enum, I just have to know that it exists.

I hope that is a bit more clear on what I am trying to do.

Comment: It depends what's inside Status. Names will be fixed but values will change? In this case use a "fake" enum. Names will change (and optionally values)? Then use a dictionary with private constants. As alternative pick an opaque type (it holds a string/integer but it's another type, just to make it a little bit more type-safety).

Comment: Adriano...Nothing inside of Status will be fixed. in one project Status might be defined as "{ In Progress = 1, Completed = 2}" in another project it might be defined as "{ Open =1, Resolved = 2}".

Comment: If you can not prevent usage of the same numbers for different enum values, you will have to use string as a key instead of int. See edit to my last example.

Comment: @user1443233 are you using VS2k10? I suggest something similar to an opaque type (to let data usable by your library) and a T4-TT to publish them to your clients. Of course it depends how much your care to type-safety (probably it's not a real problem here, a dictionary is pretty enough).

Answer (score 2):

If you want each client to see different enum values (in a different assembly version), then using an enum is a bad solution - changes will break client code...

Using an enum **might** work (as long as the enum names and assembly name are the same and the assembly isn't signed) - you could just swap the assembly. However, if a value is used anywhere in the code that isn't there at the end you'll end up with an exception. Also, you may have the explicitly number the values, to make sure different subsets of the values won't end up with the same number for different values or different numbers for the same value.

Instead **consider using a dynamically built collection**, e.g. a list, a dictionary or a database table. **Or just give the same assembly with the same superset of enum values to everyone** and let the users decide which values are relevant to them (perhaps use significant prefixes for values as a convention).

Or you could use a combination of the two...

**Generate** a different structure (**different type name (or namespace) and assembly name**) per site with different properties (according to site's profile) and one master structure for the service that accepts the structures. Have all the structures implement the same interface, which you expect to receive...

```
public interface IStatus
{
    string GetKey();
}

public struct ClientXStatus : IStatus
{
    private readonly string _key;

    private ClientXStatus(string key)
    {
        _key = key;
    }

    // Don't forget default for structs is 0,
    // therefore all structs should have a "0" property.
    public ClientXStatus Default
    {
        get
        {
            return new ClientXStatus();
        }
    }

    public ClientXStatus OptionB
    {
        get
        {
            return new ClientXStatus(10);
        }
    }

    string IStatus.GetKey()
    {
        return _key;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is IStatus) && ((IStatus)obj).GetKey() == _key;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _key.GetHashCode();
    }

    public static bool operator==(ClientXStatus x, IStatus y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public static bool operator==(IStatus x, ClientXStatus y)
    {
        return y.Equals(x);
    }

    public static bool operator!=(ClientXStatus x, IStatus y)
    {
        return !x.Equals(y);
    }

    public static bool operator!=(IStatus x, ClientXStatus y)
    {
        return !y.Equals(x);
    }

    // Override Equals(), GetHashCode() and operators ==, !=
    // So clients can compare structures to each other (to interface)
}
```

Use a master struct for the service:

```
public struct MasterStatus : IStatus
{
    private readonly string _key;

    private MasterStatus(string key)
    {
        _key = key;
    }

    // Don't forget default for structs is 0,
    // therefore all structs should have a "0" property.
    public MasterStatus Default
    {
        get
        {
            return new MasterStatus();
        }
    }

    // You should have all the options here
    public MasterStatus OptionB
    {
        get
        {
            return new MasterStatus(10);
        }
    }

    // Here use implicit interface implementation instead of explicit implementation
    public string GetKey()
    {
        return _key;
    }

    public static implicit operator MasterStatus(IStatus value)
    {
        return new MasterStatus(value.GetKey());
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MasterStatus value)
    {
        return new value._key;
    }

    // Don't forget to implement Equals, GetHashCode,
    // == and != like in the client structures
}
```

Demo service code:

```
public void ServiceMethod(IStatus status)
{
    switch (status.GetKey())
    {
        case (string)MasterStructA.OptionB:
            DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public void ChangeStatus(IStatus status)
{
    _status = (MasterStatus)status;
}
```

This way you:

1. Use code generation to prevent collision of values.
2. Force users to use compile time checks (no int values or string values) by hiding values (as private) and only accepting your structures.
3. Use real polymorphism in the service's code (an interface) and not a error-prone hack.
4. Use immutable value types (like enums) and not reference types.

Comment: Side question: as @David pointed out many projects use an approach _base class + properties_ because of static checking. Why we don't have a dictionary, for example, of colors in the framework? Why StringComparer is implemented with this approach? Hard-coding strings is tedious and error-prone.

Comment: The list of Colors doesn't change between locations. If you want colors that aren't in the list, you use... a string e.g. "#ff0080" or numbers e.g. 255, 0, 0x80. Using different static information in the same structure in different versions is worse than hard coding strings. (Something which I **do** avoid doing when possible.)

Comment: @Adriano I added an alternative approach I once used (for a different kind of problem). It is both static and hack-free (and it prevents users from providing wrong int too).

Comment: @DanntVarod We have strongly typed classes for ADO.NET and for configuration (just as example). All this effort to avoid strings. By the way there are **not** different static values for different versions (you **change configuration**, **not code**).

Comment: I like the new approach, I think it's often a good solution for a more complex problem but I'm not sure for a simple enum replacement (I'd like to point: the enum _value_, not the set of names). I mean: if, for example, your enum is DataSourceLocation with Local or Remote. If code simply use Local to translate to a string for "localhost" and Remote to translate to a string for "\\myremoteserver" then with a simple (but safe) approach all you have to do is to change that strings in the configuration. No more than one assembly. Safe enough. No versions. Few lines of (reusable) code.

Comment: Think about DI and IoR, do not code but configure! Anyway, I think we provided a lot of information for future readers. Each one will pick the best solution for her taste and context.

Comment: @Adriano I agree, however, you may have missed a key part of the OP's question: *"The values of these Enums however will be different for each site the DLL is used on."* - This is the main concern I addressed in my answer and this is why I was concerned about your answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean (after one day...LOL). It depends what he means with "values". If values can change (but names don't) then I do not appreciate the dictionary at all. If both names and values can change then my solution isn't viable at all so the dictionary (or something more complicated) is the only way. In that case we may even argue why he didn't use more than one enum... :)

Comment: @Adriano LOL finally! I understood that each client gets a different subset of the enum values (by that I mean the names) and warned that he must make sure that the mapping to int must be 1:1 with the name through out all the clients.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. It will take a few reads to completely understand, but let me try to give a better example of what I am looking at here.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide WHERE to put your constants. Then you can transform your `enum` to static properties.

For example:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

Can be changed to (first naive approach):

```
public static class MyFakeEnum
{
    public static int Value1
    {
        get { return GetActualValue("Value1"); }
    }

    public static int Value2
    {
        get { return GetActualValue("Value2"); }
    }

    private static int GetActualValue(string name)
    {
        // Put here the code to read the actual value
        // from your favorite source. It can be a database, a configuration
        // file, the registry or whatever else. Consider to cache the result.
    }
}
```

This simply will provide required constants but you'll have to throw away compile-time check for the type if you'll need `MyFakeEnum` as parameter. For a better solution you can follow, for example, what Microsoft did (more or less) for `System.Drawing.Color`.

```
public sealed class MyFakeEnum
{
    public static readonly MyFakeEnum Value1 = new MyFakeEnum("Value1");
    public static readonly MyFakeEnum Value2 = new MyFakeEnum("Value2");

    private MyFakeEnum(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(MyFakeEnum value)
    {
        return GetActualValue(value._name);
    }

    private string _name;
}
```

Of course you should provide proper overides at least for `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString`.

**Pro**

- It can be an upgrade from an existing `enum`. Code won't be breaked and you may just need to recompile.
- You can use it as strongly typed parameter. For example: `void DoSomething(MyFakeEnum value)` is valid and callers can't pass something else (note that this is one of the reasons because enums are considered weak).
- If you implement all the required operators you can use the normal syntax for comparison: `value == MyFakeEnum::Value1`.
- With a little bit of code you may even implement the `FlagsAttribute` syntax.
- You do not change the normal syntax of enums: `MyFakeEnum.Value1`.
- You can implement any number of implicit/explicit conversion operators to/from your type and any conversion will be safe and checked in the point it's done (this is not true again with standard enums).
- You do not have hard-coded strings that can be breaked by changes and won't be catched until they cause a run-time error (yes, run-time). Using, for example, a dictionary if you'll change the definitions then you'll have to search all your code for that string.

**Cons**

- First implementation is longer because you have to write *support* code (but for any new value you'll simply add a new line).
- Value list is fixed and must be known at compile time (this is not an issue if you're searching a replacement for an `enum` because it's fixed too).

With this solution you may *save* more or less the same syntax you had with standard enums.

Comment: I don't agree with your solution, however, at least now it will compile (added missing types).

Comment: @DannyVarod yes, first example is pretty naive! I was still editing the answer to provide more options anyway thank you, I did eat "int" in the declarations!

Comment: There is actually an open-source project named Tarantino that uses this approach -- see [here](https://bitbucket.org/headspringlabs/tarantino/src/4ac992ab8c14/src/Tarantino.Core/Commons/Model/Enumerations/Enumeration.cs).

Comment: @David nice project, they even provide some of the "standard" Enum functions. It's a very common technique starting from the framework itself (enums are pretty weak) so I guess many projects use it.

Comment: Using a *dictionary* would give the same functionality (string --> int) without writing a property for each value. (You could wrap it with a class that initializes the values either hardcoded or from a config file/DB) and has an indexer property... see update to my answer for details.

Comment: Using static properties will leave you with the same code breaking problems as using an enum - different versions may cause missing properties and break using code (at run time if you swap the assembly or compile time if not).

Comment: @DannyVarod it's another approach. What's better depends on context. With a dictionary you're forced to replace the enum used as parameter in a function with a string and you won't have any compile-time checking (`void foo(MyEnum value)` will be `void foo(string value)`). Moreover it'll change the syntax to check for equality (you can't write `value == MyFakeEnum.Value1' if you're using a dictionary). It may matters or not but this can bee seen as an _upgrade from_ an enum (just rebuild). Usually I prefer the dictionary for lists of unknown values.

Comment: @DannyVarod you do not have to swap the assembly. To change values you'll change configuration. If they break at compile-time...good, **it's what I want**. Do not forget that if you **hard-code strings** to access the dictionary then to change anything will break your code but you will not have any error at compile-time (and that's evil).

Comment: Compile time checking is meant for constant sets of values (or at least sets that only have values added to the end in newer versions), not for different values.

Comment: @Adriano In this case, you'll just have to use a different method for check validity e.g. unit testing.

Comment: @DannyVarod I'm sorry that compiler does not provide compile-time checking even for formatting string! More you check at compile time and more you'll sleep well in production, if it can be checked at compile time **why** you have to delegate to something else? If he was using an enum then he is working with a **finite and known** set of values. They can be checked at compile time. Plus: in the example we're using `int` but it can be a string or a class derived from `MyFakeEnum' that implements an algorithm...